# Alternating series? Determine whether the series is convergent, absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent, or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I find the convergence of the series below? I tried the alternating series test, but I don't think its parameters are being fulfilled properly.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{ln(ln(ln(ln(ln(n)))))} =  ?$$

Comment: The series isn't even defined for $n=2$

Comment: @kingW3 I know but that's what I was given to solve

Comment: Assuming you start the series at an index for which it is actually defined, what goes wrong with the alternating series test?

Comment: @kccu bn is not positive but is decreasing

Comment: The alt. series test only examines the unsigned terms, so these are certainly positive once the bottom is (again, that's an issue with the indexing in the problem).

Comment: @svyas33 For large enough $n$, $\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))))>0$. Only the end behavior of the series matters for determining convergence, so we can ignore finitely many negative terms at the beginning.

Comment: alright thanks @kccu

Comment: To see that the series does not converge absolutely, we note that $\log(x)<x$ so that for $n>e^{e^{e^{e^e}}}$

$$\frac1{\log(\log(\log(\log(\log(n)))))}>\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for your instructor's cuteness and the resulting error in the initial index, it does converge by the AST.  A composition of increasing functions is increasing, so the denominator in fact increases and so its reciprocal (unsigned) decreases.  As clear, these unsigned terms go to $0$ as the bottom grows without bound (albeit slowly), so it converges by the AST.

Also, there's no way this converges absolutely.  You can probably get that from comparison or limit comparison.